# Sending Emails- Could not resolve hostname "smpt.gmail.com"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a project and have ran into an error that unity could not resolve the hostname of smpt.gmail.com . Before anyone asks I have also added 2 step to my email account and changed the account to what I need to do for the password part. Its just that for some reason I cannot seem to get the email to be send out.
I followed this youtube video up to the part of where he talks about sending text messages:
youtube.com/watch?v=hw0XvUuzAcA&t=303s
I followed the code exactly but changed the password and email to what they actually need to be. But even after doing so I still get this error. Thank you for any help given.

Comment: Please add the code along with the exact error you are getting. Nobody is going to watch a YouTube video and nobody can read your mind.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [My web form is not working properly with SMTP](https://support.google.com/googlecloud/answer/10748445?hl=en), [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) , and https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**smtp**.gmail.com

Not **smpt**

I need to add some text for this answer.

Comment: Thank you I just realised now.